# How can I sign a raw message (without first hashing it) in Bouncy Castle?

Tags: java, cryptography, digital-signature, bouncycastle

I'm working with Bouncy Castle Library, and can't find the way to sign a raw message without hashing/padding it first. I'm not sure what parameters to pass as `alg`.

When signing a digest with PKCS v1.5 padding, I was using: "SHA1WithRSA" , "SHA256WithRSA", etc. (According to the digest type).

```
signature = Signature.getInstance(alg, JCEProvider.CRYPTO_PROVIDER_NAME);
```

Comment: A signature is typically defined by encrypting the hash of a message with the user's private key. If, for whatever reason, you dont want the hash portion, you could use your standard encryption algorithm but pass the private key instead of the public key. Although, keep in mind that this does not preserve the confidentiality or integrity of a message. That method only provides non-repudiation.

Comment: What you want is called 'signature with recovery'. See the [SignerWithRecovery](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/SignerWithRecovery.html) interface and implementing classes.

Comment: Note hashing and padding are separate, and RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 includes ASN.1 encoding with AlgorithmIdentifier _plus_ padding with 01 FF ... 00; see rfc3447. In addition to the direct/'lightweight' API suggested by @JamesKPolk you can get type-01 padding but _not_ ASN.1 encoding via the provider interface with algorithm `NoneWithRSA` or simply `RSA`. Bouncy provider can also do PSS with various hashes, and without as any of `RSASSA-PSS RawRSASSA-PSS NoneWithRSASSA-PSS`

Comment: Eh, I don't get it. You can do this without even using Bouncy Castle. Why is that a requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Raw signing is nothing more than modular exponentiation. Now there seem to be two options, but basically only one will remain. I'll explain below.

First of all, you'd think that using a `Signature` with `"NoneWithRSA"` should work. The algorithm does exist, but unfortunately it still pads; it just strips the ASN.1 structure indicating the hash function and value. So that one is not available.

Although [signing is not the same as encryption](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15997/is-rsa-encryption-of-a-cryptographic-hash-with-a-private-key-the-same-as-signatu), both operations in the end rely on modular exponentiation. So it is fortunately possible to use a `Cipher` instance to create the functionality you need:

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

Cipher rsa = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
rsa.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, kp.getPrivate());
byte[] signatureUsingCipher = rsa.doFinal("owlstead"
        .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
System.out.println(Hex.toHexString(signatureUsingCipher));
```

Now one thing to notice here is that Bouncy Castle does perform a somewhat different operation than the SunJCE provider of Oracle. Instead of just removing the padding, it also *forgets to put the ciphertext through the I2OSP algorithm* (see the PKCS#1 standard), which properly encodes to the output size of the modulus. So you can have a smaller ciphertext than 128 bytes for specific key / plaintext combinations. This is very easy to see by encrypting the value 0, where the output will be zero bytes.

Finally note that specifying `Cipher.ENCRYPT` mode or `Cipher.DECRYPT` mode doesn't make a difference; both simply perform modular exponentiation. However, Cipher.DECRYPT is more likely to expect a private key, which is why I used it in above code.

---

You can generate a key pair for testing above code like this:

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
kpg.initialize(1024);
KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
```

---

**Warning**: signature generation without secure padding is insecure; [it may result in existential forgery attacks](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/12780/1172). You can only use this as building block for to create a secure scheme.

Answer (score 0):

```
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("NONEwithRSA","BC");
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Signature.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The question asked for sign without hashing **or padding** and `"NONEwithRSA"` certainly pads.

Answer (score 0):

// ECDSA Digital Signature Verification in Java

```
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("NONEwithECDSA");
```